Comparing really small numbers fails in Pine script
Pine script fails comparing small numbers. Here is the example of log output.
Code:
log.info("I => bar_idx: {0, number}\nhigh: {1, number, #.############}\nlow: {2, number, #.############}\nhigh_1: {3, number, #.############}\nlow_1: {4, number, #.############}", bar_idx, high_v, low_v, high1_v, low1_v)
log.warning("\n{0, number, #.############} < {1, number, #.############}: {2}\n{3, number, #.############} > {4, number, #.############}: {5}", high_v, high1_v, high_v < high1_v, low_v, low1_v, low_v > low1_v)
log.warning("\n{0, number, #.############} > {1, number, #.############}: {2}\n{3, number, #.############} < {4, number, #.############}: {5}", high_v, high1_v, high_v > high1_v, low_v, low1_v, low_v < low1_v)
log.warning("\n{0, number, #.############} == {1, number, #.############}: {2}\n{3, number, #.############} == {4, number, #.############}: {5}", high_v, high1_v, high_v == high1_v, low_v, low1_v, low_v == low1_v)

Output:
[2023-04-24T00:00:00.000-00:00]: I => bar_idx: 1
high: 0.000000000028
low: 0.000000000007
high_1: 0.000000000019
low_1: 0.000000000006

[2023-04-24T00:00:00.000-00:00]:
0.000000000028 < 0.000000000019: false
0.000000000007 > 0.000000000006: false

[2023-04-24T00:00:00.000-00:00]:
0.000000000028 > 0.000000000019: false
0.000000000007 < 0.000000000006: false

[2023-04-24T00:00:00.000-00:00]:
0.000000000028 == 0.000000000019: true
0.000000000007 == 0.000000000006: true

Why are these false?
0.000000000007 > 0.000000000006: false
0.000000000028 > 0.000000000019: false

Why are these true?
0.000000000028 == 0.000000000019: true
0.000000000007 == 0.000000000006: true

Is there some way of getting around this behavior?

This question is similar to: Is floating-point math broken?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are mixing formatted numbers and their unformatted comparison... Display the numbers as they are to see what they are and their comparison.

@njzk2 I presume you are correct that my issue arises from the floating point precission.

@karatedog I had to format the log output otherwise I just get 0 in the log output. Bool comparison itself is done with the unformatted numbers.

I get equality comparison is no no in this case, but what about bigger/smaller comparison? Does it make sense to multiply small numbers with some big number before comparison?
